How would I have an array of reference values?
Here is the code:
int test = 5;
int[] array1 = { test };
int[] array2 = { test };
array1[0] += 5;
array2[0] += 5;
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.WriteLine(array1[0]);
Console.WriteLine(array2[0]);

And here is the output:
5
10
10

My question is would it be possible for all of the outputs to be 15 instead? I.e. by adding 5 to the first value in array1 we are adding 5 to test, which becomes 10 and is also in array2, so when we add 5 there it becomes 15.
My idea of how I think this would be done is with references e.g. having an array of references but I'm not sure how I could go about this?

I think you should be more clearly about what you mean by having "ints" that are"references" when you are talking about ints. Ints are not reference types. What do you really want to do? Why would you store this value in three places? Why can't you create a type/class that better encapsulate your data in a way that also makes its use and purpose more plain and easier to work with?

^^ smells like "primitive obsession".

If you mean a reference as in the ref keyword or a C++ reference, then no, you can't put those in an array in C#.

In C# data types can be of two types:

Value Types: the variable holds the value. Example: int, Struct, etc.
Reference Types: the variable holds a reference (memory address) in which the value is stored. Example: Class

If you would like to get an array of reference types, you should create an array of them (don't use deep copy)
you can do like this:
    public class ValueHolder
    {
        public int Value;
    }

    ValueHolder test = new ValueHolder { Value = 5 }; 

    ValueHolder[] array1 = { test }; // Shallow copy of test
    ValueHolder[] array2 = { test };

    array1[0].Value += 5;
    array2[0].Value += 5;

    Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(array1[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(array2[0].Value);
}


ValueHolder also known as StrongBox<T>.

You can do something like this:
public class RefValue<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public RefValue(T val) { this.Value = val;}
    public static implicit operator T(RefValue<T> s) => s.Value;
}

var test = new RefValue<int>(5);
RefValue<int>[] array1 = { test };
RefValue<int>[] array2 = { test };

array1[0].Value += 5;
array2[0].Value += 5;
Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
Console.WriteLine(array1[0]);
Console.WriteLine(array2[0]);

See it work here:

http://dotnetfiddle.net/EEw1O0


This works because it is the type which is either a value type or a reference type. An int is a value type, A class is a reference type. (I am missing an explanation in your answer.)

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Also because we are only updating a property of the object, not the object itself, and both arrays plus the variable all refer to the same object instance.

One of the options is using pointers. Caution, they should be wrapped with unsafe.
unsafe
{
  int test = 5;
  int* testPtr = &test;
  int*[] array1 = { testPtr};
  int*[] array2 = { testPtr};
  *array1[0] += 5;
  *array2[0] += 5;

  Console.WriteLine(test); //15
  Console.WriteLine(*array1[0]); //15
  Console.WriteLine(*array2[0]); //15
}

